# Setting a VM boot CD via PowerCLI

Tags: powershell, vmware-vsphere, pxe-boot, powercli

I have a sneaking suspicion that this may be a bug, but I'm definitely willing to entertain the possibility that I'm doing things wrong.

I have a VMware virtual machine in $vm, and I'm trying to assign a boot CD for it. $vm is powered off.

The documented method seems pretty straightforward:

```
Set-CDDrive -CD (Get-CDDrive -vm $vm) -IsoPath "[datastorename] \whatever.iso" -StartConnected 1
```

Now, when I start the VM, it immediately tries to PXEboot. I turn off the machine, and in the vSphere client, I edit the VM's properties, go to "CD/DVD drive 1", and verify, "Device Status" has a checkmark next to "Connect at power on".

Here's the crazy thing. When I uncheck that box, then check it again, then start the VM, it boots from the ISO.

I've done it again and again, with the console open, with it closed, and every time, I can set the StartConnected flag on the CLI, and the GUI reflects the setting, but only after I mark the checkbox manually does it actually boot from the ISO.

Is there a step that I'm neglecting to perform in PowerCLI to get this setting to "take"?

Answer (score 1):

From the PowerCLI reference online, I see the following example (replace value after `-ISOPath` with your datastore and name/path for .iso file like so`"[yourdatastore] IsoFolder\$iso"`):

```
$cd = New-CDDrive -VM $vm -ISOPath "[sof-20666-esx:storage1] ISO\testISO.iso"
Set-CDDrive -CD $cd -StartConnected -Connected
```

Answer (score 1):

The first backslash in the `ISOPath` may very well be the problem. I'm doing the exact same thing in our provisioning scripts, it looks like this:

```
Get-CDDrive $VM | Set-CDDrive -IsoPath "[DATASTORE] ISO\BOOT.ISO" -StartConnected:$true -Confirm:$false
```

Also, if you're providing boolean values to arguments that accept a boolean (like `StartConnected`), try to make it a habit to use a semi-colon like the example above. If you happen to have a Cmdlet of function that accepts more than one unnamed argument, your `1` may be mis-interpreted as a new argument in the function call, rather than the value of the argument you intended.

So, don't use `-StartConnected 1`, but rather use `-StartConnected:1` or `-StartConnected:$true`.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring the boot order of a VMware VM is described in [this Knowledge Base article](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2011654).

Summary of the PowerCLI variant:

1. Create the specs

```powershell
   $vm = Get-VM myvm
   $spec = New-Object -TypeName VMware.Vim.VirtualMachineConfigSpec
   $spec.BootOptions = $vm.ExtensionData.Config.BootOptions
   $disk1 = New-Object -TypeName VMware.Vim.VirtualMachineBootOptionsBootableDiskDevice
   $disk1.DeviceKey = (Get-HardDisk -Name 'Hard disk 1' -VM $vm).ExtensionData.Key
   $cdrom = New-Object -TypeName VMware.Vim.VirtualMachineBootOptionsBootableCdromDevice
   $spec.BootOptions.BootOrder = $cdrom,$disk1
```

2. Power down the VM
   *(The configuration can only be set in PowerOff state)*

```powershell
   $vm |Stop-VMGuest
```

3. Apply the specifications

```powershell
   $vm.ExtensionData.ReconfigVM($spec)
```

4. Start the VM again

```powershell
   $vm |Start-VM
```

The VM will boot from the mounted iso.

Notes:

- The config will be persistent. If you want to revert this, you need to do this manually (`$spec.BootOptions.BootOrder = $disk1,$cdrom`)
- You need to set the iso to be connected on startup